# How can I force a re-render of a component in MainLayout?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I know one answer is don't use MainLayout for this one page, but I prefer to not do that as we then have to keep 2 layout pages in sync on every change in them - and that's just asking for divergence.

Here's the problem. This is my MainLayout (simplified)

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    <ChildContent>
        <main class="@pageClass">
            <PopupMessageBox>
                <header class="main-header">
                    <PrimaryNav UserAvatarUrl="@UserAvatarUrl" IsManagerOrSysAdmin="@(Principal.IsManagerOrSysAdmin())" />
                </header>
                <div class="main-content">
                    @Body
                </div>
    </ChildContent>
```

For one `@Body` page we need to have `<PrimaryNav>` have a slightly different menu selection. In `<PrimaryNav>` we can determine what page is in `@Body`, but having the page change does not cause `<PrimaryNav>` to re-render.

Is there a way to force it to re-render on every page change?

Comment: On questions like this I wish I could conclude the question with "Or is this a bad idea?" But opinions cannot be asked for. (They can however be given.)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/sections?view=aspnetcore-8.0. Is now the more elegant way to do this. Your page can define its own menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@body` is the current page component.  It's available in `Routes` in the `Router` as `routeData`.

Here I'm simply cascading the `Type`.

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue Name="PageComponent" Value="routeData.PageType">
            <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
</Router>
```

The value will be refreshed with a render cascade on each navigation.

You can then capture the cascade in `NavMenu`.  Here's a demo that only shows the `Weather` nav link when you are on `Home`.

```cs
<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">BlazorApp1</a>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" />

<div class="nav-scrollable" onclick="document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler').click()">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="bi bi-house-door-fill-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <span class="bi bi-plus-square-fill-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
            </NavLink>
        </div>

@if(_isHome)
        {
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="weather">
                <span class="bi bi-list-nested-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Weather
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        }
    </nav>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "PageComponent")] private Type? RouteType { get; set; }

    private bool _isHome => RouteType == typeof(Home);
}
```

Comment: As always, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could firstly call a method in the Parent(MainLayout) from ChildComponent(@body). Then in the "MainLayout" call a method in the "nav" .
Try following sample which calling `StateHasChanged();` in the "NavMenu" from Counter.razor.

Create a static Number which for render test of NavMenu.

```
    public static class Number
    {
       public static int value;
    }
```

NavMenu.cs (Add @number.value behind Counter for render test)

```
...
               <span class="bi bi-plus-square-fill-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
               @Number.value
           </NavLink> 
...  

@code{
    public void RefreshState()
    {
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

MainLayout.cs   (call methods 1.cascadingvalue: child->parent;  2.@ref: parent->child  )

```
...
 <NavMenu @ref="nav" />
...    
            <CascadingValue Value="this">
                @Body
            </CascadingValue>
...
@code{
    NavMenu nav;
    public void CallMethodInNav()
    {
        nav.RefreshState();
    }
}
```

Counter.cs  (using cascading parameter to call method from parent)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    [CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout _mainLayout { get; set; }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        Number.value = currentCount;
        _mainLayout.CallMethodInNav();
    }
}
```

Test Result  (The @Number.value keep re-render when click counter)
[image]

You could using similar at "OnInitialized" for pages you want to trigger nav refresh.